# Cannot get Glassfish to log my apps debuug level logs

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4

I am using commons-logging swith the following `commons-logging.properties`:
`org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger`

I have set my app logger to `FINEST` in GF4 ui management console but it only logs `INFO` messages. Any ideas why?

Also where is it more appropriate to set my log levels, under server-config or default-config?

Thanks

Comment: Looking a little closer, the server logs are being written in the log file correctly. They are not though in the eclipse console (I can see only INFO) messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer in Oracle's documentation. GF3 (and apparently GF4) set the min level to the root level to `INFO`. The global log settings must be changed in GF props file: logging.properties which is usually under the domain/conf directory

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghmep/index.html